# Random Access files > 2GB with Android SDK

Tags: android, file-io

can anyone tell me how to random access a file beyond 2GB with android SDK. 
I was trying to seek to a position > 2147483647 and got the exception: "Value too large for defined datatype". That is odd as the parameter for the seek command is type "long". See the code example for details:

```
RandomAccessFile    BigFile;
BigFile = new RandomAccessFile(sMyFileName, "r");
BigFile.seek(2147483648);
   --> Exception
```

Thanks for any help,
Michael

Answer (score 3):

That is the result of the exception bubbling up from the native/IO (system) layer. It doesn't have to do with the size of the type in the language/VM itself. The error at the lower lever is EOVERFLOW ("Value to large for defined data type"). [lseek](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek), for instance, lists this error.

Hypothesis: The underlying system access isn't 64-bit "aware" :-) Some *real* JREs also had this problem historically, IIRC. Not sure what the story on android is.

**Edit:** The thread at [FAT32 file size limited to 2GB](http://markmail.org/thread/qv6u64qw4sfwbzkc) seems to relate the Android 2.x (and contains details/hints/hypothesis about the kernel build and/or IO lib limitations -- consensus is "it doesn't work").

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually i read this article while i was searching for a solution. But my hope was that they are all wrong and there IS a solution. :-/ But i think you are right. THe underlaying IO system seems not to use 64bit. (But lseek64 is actually part of the Android OS - why is it not used ?)