# Android RandomAccessFile java.io.IOException: Value too large for defined data type at seek

Tags: android, nio

I can see this question is asked frequently however my situation is different. I observe the exception at simple seek operation for a channel, here is my code:

```
 private RandomAccessFile channel;
   .....
 try {
        channel.seek(pos);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.printf("Seek file size %d  seek to %d%n", originalSize, pos);
        throw ioe;
    }
```

I added the try just to catch values at which the exception happened. So I see something like that in log:

```
08-25 22:50:11.662: W/System.err(18839): Seek file size 2198818800  seek to 2196985856
08-25 22:50:11.682: E/wavpack(18839): Value too large for defined data type
08-25 22:50:11.682: E/wavpack(18839): java.io.IOException: Value too large for defined data type
08-25 22:50:11.682: E/wavpack(18839):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.seek(Native Method)
08-25 22:50:11.682: E/wavpack(18839):   at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.seek(BlockGuard.java:210)
```

I do not have Android source handy to figure out what was actually triggered the exception. And the code is working fine if I use Oracle Java under Windows or Linux with the same source data. Any clue?

Comment: What version of android are you running this on? It seems to have been fixed in honeycomb https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21696

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random Access files > 2GB with Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936402/random-access-files-2gb-with-android-sdk)

Comment: I understand that it is Android underline implementation bug. Any work around? Many phones have not upgradeable version of Android OS. Maybe I can subclass RandomAccessFile and then wrap the method to call some private native method? BTW duplicate question has no answer except you deal with Android bug.

Comment: It's a known bug that was fixed in honeycomb... If you need to support older OS versions I suppose you can write your own I/O class? Android *is* open source, after all.

Comment: Unfortunately Android is commercial software. When you buy a phone you cover cost of open source included with it, it is why I and other expect low level bugs in it. If you are crazy about to earn answered question greens, please put answer from your comment I will mark it as covered my question, I use for now a work around as sequential read after max value seek.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to point you towards the reason. I did answer the question below. Glad you are able to come up with a workaround. It's worth noting that you can monitor the % of users on each platform, and raise your minimum supported version as more users upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known bug pre-honeycomb as detailed [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21696).

From your comments I see you are testing on an older OS, that is probably why you are seeing the error. If you can test on a newer OS, you should be able to confirm this.

As for solving this error - if you have control over the files being read, you can try to deal with files only under 2GB. Otherwise you might need to look at other ways to parse the file, or perhaps writing your own file I/O class.

If you don't care about older devices you can always restrict your app by adding `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

To check if your program is running on a version that will require the workaround, use

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
     // only version older than gingerbread
}
```

Comment: I use a work around as
if (pos > Integer.MAX_VALUE-1) {
   seek(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
   int n = (int)(pos - Integer.MAX_VALUE);
   byte buf[] = new byte[1024*1024]; // once statically allocated
   for(int i=0,k=n/1024/1024; i<k;i++)
 read(buf);
   for(int i=0,k=n%(1024*1024); i<k;i++)
 this.channel.read();
} else
  seek(pos);
Since it isn't required for honeycomb and after what rough check can I do?

Comment: @DonCesarD'Bazar I edited my answer to add a way to check the system version at runtime

Comment: Thanks, funny thing that all IE including 10 have similar bug for calculation content length of uploaded content, I assume it is common problem of all big companies lacking of knowledge of basic computer science.